# Warning about ownership of "/var/db/sudo/lectured" whenever using sudo

Tags: sudo, nixos

Whenever I use `sudo` on my system I get this warning:

```
sudo: /var/db/sudo/lectured is owned by uid 84, should be 0
```

What does it mean and what can I do to fix it?

I am using NixOS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The directory and what's created inside is what presents the message to the user upon becoming `sudo` which is normally something along the lines of:

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things: 

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

The directory `/var/db/sudo/lectured` file should be owned by root which has `uid 0` but in your case, it isn't. This command will show you the ownership:

```
ls -d /var/db/sudo/lectured
```

As it's not owned by root, you need to change the ownership to root via:

```
chown root:root /var/db/sudo/lectured
```

The permissions should also be `700`. You can change it to this if needed via:

```
chmod 700 /var/db/sudo/lectured
```

If there are files inside where the ownership and permissions are wrong then you can use the following:

```
chown -R root /var/db/sudo/lectured
```

`cd` into the folder and:

```
chmod 600 *
```

Comment: +1. What about adding `-R` to `chown` to change ownership also of the content of the directory, and maybe also to `chmod` for the permissions of the content?

Comment: The files inside do need to be owned by root but the group is normally the user's group and the permissions should be 600. I'll add your suggestion to my answer.